# How to get the cell address of Max() in vba

Tags: excel, vba, max, cell

Hi I have something like this, and want to store the cell address of the max number, to make a substraction of "x" parameter on the max number

SUNDAY

3

10

2

0

9.93

Eg. x= 3, maxvalue= 10 ---> new table maxvalue=7

SUNDAY

3

7

2

0

9.93

Im working with a Sub

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub WhereIsMax()
    Dim rLook As Range, Biggest As Variant, Where As String
    Set rLook = Range("A1:Z100")
    Biggest = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rLook)
    Where = rLook.Find(What:=Biggest, After:=rLook(1), LookIn:=xlValues).Address
    MsgBox Where
End Sub
```